# Calling Google IAM generateAccessToken API always returns error

Tags: service-accounts, google-apis-explorer, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I'm facing the issue where I am not able to generate an Access Token for Google IAM Service Account using this [method](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/generateAccessToken) . 
I've got my personal OAuth2 access token using:
`gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`

I've got all the necessary roles (`roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator`) but when I cURL the API I always get an error response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

This is how full curl request looks like:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'authorization: Bearer ya29.AASDSADASDASDi9C1yAXXXXXXZzLtDDrCAzblqF_qi5sKvMZcHieBADASDASDTNJiOKrqJBffb4Moh3gTgiTbDgMIF1XDQU5JZ31aACs0aUbI4wgeqV2Q' https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<PROJECT_NAME>/serviceAccounts/<SA_NAME>@<PROJECT_NAME>.iam.gserviceaccount.com:generateAccessToken -d '{"scope": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]}'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems in your API call.

1. The Service Account Name is a path parameter and must be URL encoded. The `@` character is not valid. Use `%40` in its place (as an example of correct encoding).
2. The URI specifies a `PROJECT_NAME`. This is not correct. You need to use a `-` (hyphen/dash character). Example `projects/-/serviceAccounts`.

You also need to have the permission `iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken` attached to one of the roles that are assigned to the account that created the request Access Token use in this API request. This will cause a different error if incorrect. Just a tip as you get to the next step.

Comment: Replacing `@` with `%40` and `projects/<PROJECT_NAME>/serviceAccounts` with `projects/-/serviceAccounts` solved the problem! Thanks @john-hanley

Comment: great, had the same issue - now it works! I could have sworn there are docs/examples where "-" in "projects/-" is used as a placeholder for the project ID.